# How to add pre-generated HTML pages in Kentico 13

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc

1. My Designing team use to generate static HTML pages (html files, css, JS, fonts etc) and use to share zip with us.
2. We are looking forward to add these pages in Kentico 13 Core.
3. I have created the custom page type having one field of type File.
4. Use to upload pre-generated HTML file from Pages app using above created page type.

But it use to attached as attachment and dont use to show contents. It did work with Kentico portal engine but didnt find ant option under Kentico 13 Core.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what type of behavior you are looking for, but if you are expecting to be able to customize HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in Kentico Xperience or Kentico 12 MVC the way it works in Kentico Portal Engine, that's just not possible.

Using MVC requires either:

1. Templates be [coded ahead of time in Razor](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/retrieving-content/displaying-page-content) `.cshtml` files
2. Templates be designed as composable pieces that can be built up as [Page Builder](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development) components (like Sections, Widgets, Page Templates)

Content Managers then will create Pages in the Content Tree and add their content to those Pages. Those Pages either have Razor Controllers/Views associated with them to render their content (and related content) or use the Page Builder to combine components that display content.

If you want to display Attachments in a Page, you can follow the [instructions in the documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/retrieving-content/displaying-page-attachments).

If you want Content Managers to be able to upload HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files to be displayed/rendered on the site, you'll need to come up with a custom solution - potentially using [Media Libraries](https://docs.xperience.io/managing-website-content/working-with-files/media-library-files) and a custom coded solution.